# What's the correct way to setup multiple environments (other than production) for the Server-Side Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

The **client-side GTM** containers allowed configuring multiple environments. It was especially useful for testing GTM in staging, QA and whatnot first.

It is available under: [https://tagmanager.google.com/#/admin/accounts/<ACCOUNT_ID>/containers/<CLIENT_SIDE_CONTAINER_ID>/environments](https://example.com)

[image: gtm-client-side-environments]

With custom environment, the code snippet was updated with additional query params: `gtm_preview=env-<NUMBER>` and `gtm_auth=XXXXXXX`

---

Now for the **server-side GTM** there's no such option visible in the UI:

[image: gtm-server-side-environments]

While it displays when accessed via the same URL: [https://tagmanager.google.com/#/admin/accounts/<ACCOUNT_ID>/containers/<SERVER_SIDE_CONTAINER_ID>/environments](https://example.com), it does not help, as the code snippet does not differ compared to the production one: no extra query params are added.

---

My question is: **What's the correct way to setup multiple environments (other than production) for the Server-Side Google Tag Manager?**